# Instagram API request for posting media using web app in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web, instagram

Does Instagram API allows to post media objects(photos) using web apps?

Our web application in rails want to post some pics on Instagram site using API.

It would be helpful if there is some way to do this.

If is not possible, do we have some js feature which allows to share data?,
just like what Pinterest allows using pin_it_js.

Comment: Seems duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25033560/how-to-post-image-with-description-in-instagram-using-access-token-in-ruby/25034920#25034920

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instagram only allows the fetching of information (GET) [1]. There are however hooks which could allow you to redirect to the Instagram app which would allow users to view a predefined image[2]. There are also libraries to help you with your web app [3].

[1] - http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/

[2] - http://instagram.com/developer/iphone-hooks/

[3] - https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem

Comment: Thanks for response.
But can't we redirect to instagram using web application to upload pics? as link http://instagram.com/developer/iphone-hooks/ suggests it is for iphone apps only.

Comment: That's not possible. Also the code above will only work for iOS. The API is very much read only.